# Create a Predicate to match an entity with an entry in a Map property

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteriaquery

I'm trying to create a `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` to match entities which contain a certain key/value entry in a `Map<String,String>` property. This is in the context of Spring Data JPA and a `JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity>` repository.

```java
class MyEntity {
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  ...
  Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
}

static Specification<MyEntity> hasMetadata(String name, String value) {
  return (entity, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    Path<Map<String,String>> metadata = entity.get("metadata");

    // fixme: insert magic
    //
    // not quite right: cb.isMember(cb.literal(value), metadata) 

    return ...
  };
}
```

There is a slightly related question [CriteriaBuilder and isMember of list on entity (Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982058/criteriabuilder-and-ismember-of-list-on-entity-hibernate), but I haven't been able to glean much info from there.

A solution would be nice, but also a pointer to documentation where this is specified too. My Google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an very similar question here [jpa criteriabuilder join maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580614/jpa-criteriabuilder-join-maps), which offered up something that seems to work now

```
static Specification<MyEntity> hasMetadata(String name, String value) {
  return (entity, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    MapJoin<MyEntity, String, String> join = entity.joinMap("metadata");
    return criteriaBuilder.and(
      criteriaBuilder.equal(join.key(), name),
      criteriaBuilder.equal(join.value(), value)
    );
  };
}
```